# Darken segment separators of a UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control which has three buttons, and I want to darken the lines that separate the segments.

My code is:

```
NSArray *listArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Email",@"SMS",nil];
UISegmentedController *segmentedController = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:listArray]; 
segmentedController.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;//i have to use this style(bar) 
segmentedController.momentary = YES; 
segmentedController.frame = CGRectMake (90, CGRectGetMaxY(lbl.frame)+50, 140, 40); 
//seg.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
[segmentedController addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; 
[self.view addSubview:segmentedController];
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch the Style to textured rounded:

original (rounded):
[image]

textured rounded:
[image]

Comment: where i change through which i can dark the line of segmentedcontrol which is present at the mid of Email & SMS.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so familiar with the programmatic interface.

Comment: Try different styles which fits you segmentedController.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled;  or  UISegmentedControlStyleBezeledPlain  or UISegmentedControlStyleBar or UISegmentedControlStyleBordered